# vba excel set dynamic named ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set all the named range in one variable and export to PDF. I am able to do when I manually enter all the named range. My problem is named range are variable, sometime it will have one some time it will have more than 10. Please advice...I tried with following codes.

```
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim nName As Name

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set nName=wbBook.Names

Set rs = wbBook.Range(nNames)
rs.Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath, , , False
```

But below code works for me, when I enter range name manually..

```
Set rs = wbBook.Range("Page_1,Page_2,Page_3")
rs.Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath, , , False
```

Comment: you setup `Dim nName As Name` but in your line you have `Set rs = wbBook.Range(nNames)` , **nNames** instead of **nName**

Comment: really `Set rs = wbBook.Range("Page_1,Page_2,Page_3")` works?

Comment: Yes, That worked for me and gave me output in three pages in single PDF file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a *collection* (many objects) to an *object variable* (single object). You need to loop through the collection's objects. Usually we do this with a `For Each` loop, but in this case, as I needed to set the first element separately because of the `Union`, I have used a simple `For` loop.

Also, avoid using `.Select` if you can. Just use your objects directly.

Also note that you are talking about all the named ranges in the Workbook, and this might cause problems if you have named ranges in multiple worksheets. I haven't tested, but I doubt it would work.

```
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim rs As Range

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set rs = wbBook.Names(1).RefersToRange
For i = 2 To wbBook.Names.Count
   Set rs = Union(rs, wbBook.Names(i).RefersToRange)
Next

rs.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, strPath, , , False
```

Comment: this assumes that all _workbook_ named ranges reside in the same worksheet, otherwise `Union()` would error out.

Comment: @user3598756 true, I have mentioned this. I assumed they were all in the same sheet, otherwise OP's original code would be very far from a solution.

Comment: you're right: I only looked at your code and didn't see the initial _caveat_. As to the OP's initial code, well 'wbBook.Range' is what I'd call a "very far from solution" start...

Comment: Its working; however all the named range are printed in single page, whereas I want each named range in single page. I dynamically do the page setting to fit single page (.FitToPagesWide = 1 , .FitToPagesTall = 1) for each named range. When I name the range individually, it works. I think, we need to keep the original page settings in "rs". Will you assist me on this ?, I am very new to vba.My thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Manish! We will gladly help, but since it is a new question, please ask a new question. Also, if my answer answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the green tick mark on the left.

Comment: Hi @vacip  I posted another question, will you be able to look into this ?...Thanks!